# Concatenate object property with string in hautelook/AliceBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fixtures

I'm using Alice in a Symfony 2 bundle to load fixtures. I'm trying to customize the name of an entity using the name of a parent entity. Specifically, I have an entity, `@Report1`, whose `@Report1->name` property returns `Test Report 1`.

I'm trying to create a child entity with the name `Test Report 1 Scenario 1`. Here's my fixture file snippet:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Scenario:
  Scenario1:
    report_id: @Report1->id
    name: @Report1->name 'Scenario 1'
```

All I get back is the literal `@Report1->name 'Scenario 1'`.

If I remove the `'Scenario 1'` string from the`name:` property, I get the parent report's actual name.

Comment: The original Alice implementation is on GitHub at `nelmio/alice`

Comment: Have you tried creating custom data provider for concatenating strings? https://github.com/nelmio/alice#custom-faker-data-providers

Comment: Not yet, but thanks for the tip. I'll look into it and post results here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am using hautelook/alice-bundle 1.3.1 (nelmio/alice 2.2.0 and fzaninotto/faker 1.6.0) with **php 5.6**.

You can configure a custom data provider with a [variable-length arguments list](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) and use it in your fixtures files.

In AppBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/DataLoader.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Hautelook\AliceBundle\Doctrine\DataFixtures\AbstractLoader;

class DataLoader extends AbstractLoader
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFixtures()
    {
        return [
            __DIR__.'/../Fixtures/user.yml',
        ];
    }

    public function concat(...$strings)
    {
        $result = '';

        foreach ($strings as $string) {
            $result .= $string;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Now you can use the custom data provider like this.

In AppBundle/DataFixtures/Fixtures/user.yml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    user-{1..10}:
        firstname: <firstname()>
        lastname: <lastname()>

        email: <concat(@self->firstname, ".", @self->lastname, "@gmail.com")>
        plainPassword: 123
        username: <concat(@self->firstname, ".", @self->lastname)>
```

It's a bit tedious to write but it works.

And for php versions prior to php 5.6, you can use [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) to get the list of arguments in DataLoader.php, like this:

```
    public function concat()
    {
        $result = '';

        foreach (func_get_args() as $string) {
            $result .= $string;
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Another option that worked for me was using [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
App\Entity\User:
  users{1..150}:
    firstname: '<firstname()>'
    lastname: '<lastname()>'
    email: '<sprintf("%s.%s@gmail.com", @self->firstname, @self->lastname)>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplified version in 2022 (AliceBundle):

```php
//<symfony-project>/src/Service/FixtureProvider.php
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Faker\Provider\Base;

class FixtureProvider extends Base
{
    /**
     * From https://stackoverflow.com/a/38328847
     * @param ...$strings
     * @return string
     */
    public function concat(...$strings): string
    {
        return implode('', $strings);
    }
}
```

Note that for email strings building, you may face the ['@' sign escaping bug](https://github.com/nelmio/alice/issues/992), when using the `sprintf` strategy above. The `concat` helper strangely circumvents that.

Usage example:

```yaml
App\Entity\User:
  user_non_admin_{2..10}:
    firstName: '<firstName()>'
    lastName: '<lastName()>'
    email (unique): "<concat('nonadmin+', @self->firstName, @self->lastName, '@somedomain.com')>"
```